# XML serialization: class within a class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am serializing with xml, and I had it working with just a simple class, but when I made a secondary class, of which the simple class was just a component, the serialization stopped working.  It fails with an "Error reflecting type" error at the serialization stage.  The code is as follows:

```
public class CustomField
{
    [XmlAttribute("FieldID")]
    public string FieldID;
    [XmlAttribute("FieldValue")]
    public string FieldValue;
    public CustomField() { }
    public CustomField(string fieldID, string fieldValue)
    {
        this.FieldID = fieldID;
        this.FieldValue = fieldValue;
    }
}
[XmlType("Entry")]
public class CustomEntry
{
    [XmlAttribute("Author")]
    public string Author;
    [XmlAttribute("Title")]
    public string Title;
    [XmlAttribute("Trial")]
    public string Trial;
    [XmlAttribute("Responses")]
    public List<CustomField> Responses;
    public CustomEntry() { }
}
public static class EntrySerializer
{
    public static void SerializeObject(this CustomEntry entry, string file)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomEntry));
        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(file))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it a labeling issue with the Xml markers, or is it something else?

Comment: Nevermind, the label needs to be "XmlElement" for the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your serializer like this:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomEntry), new Type[] { typeof(CustomField) });
```

You need to inform the serializer of the additional types it is expecting to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

I usually tag with XMLRoot (two places).  I need to see sample of XML to give better answer.

```css
[XmlRoot("CustomField")]
public class CustomField
{
    [XmlAttribute("FieldID")]
    public string FieldID;
    [XmlAttribute("FieldValue")]
    public string FieldValue;
    public CustomField() { }
    public CustomField(string fieldID, string fieldValue)
    {
        this.FieldID = fieldID;
        this.FieldValue = fieldValue;
    }
}
[XmlRoot("Entry")]
public class CustomEntry
{
    [XmlAttribute("Author")]
    public string Author;
    [XmlAttribute("Title")]
    public string Title;
    [XmlAttribute("Trial")]
    public string Trial;
    [XmlAttribute("Responses")]
    public List<CustomField> Responses;
    public CustomEntry() { }
}
​
```